# Lebesgue measure of sum $ X + Y$ is infinite

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am given that $X$ is an interval of length $d > 0$ and $y_n$ is a sequence of reals such that $|y_m - y_n| > d$ if $m\neq n$  . If we let $Y =\{y_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ show that $m(X+Y) = \infty$.

Here $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Pretend for now that $X = [0,1/10]$ and $Y = \mathbb Z$ is the set of integers. The set $X + Y = \cup_n [n, n + 1/10]$ essentially "repeats" X at every integer. Since there are countably many disjoint copies of X, the measure of $X + Y$ is infinite. The general case is similar.

Comment: What do you mean countably many disjoint copies of X? And how does this imply that the measure of X + Y is infinite?

Comment: Following @ABlumenthal's suggestion:  Start with his $X$, which has measure $1/10$.  Let $Y=\{0,1,2\}$.  Then $X+Y=[0,1/10]\cup[1,11/10]\cup[2,21/10]$ and has measure $3$.  Each point in $Y$ adds another $1/10$ to the measure of $X+Y$ as long as the intervals do not overlap.  If $Y$ is infinite, the measure of $X+Y$ will be infinite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that: $$X+Y=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}(X+y_n)\tag1$$
where $X+y_n:=\{x+y_n\mid x\in X\}$.

If  $z\in (X+y_n)\cap(X+y_m)$ then $a,b\in X$ must exist with $a+y_n=z=b+y_m$ and consequently $|y_n-y_m|=|b-a|\leq d$ and $n=m$.

This tells us that the sets $X+y_n$ and $X+y_m$ are disjoint if $n\neq m$ so that the RHS of $(1)$ is a union of disjoint sets.

Then: $$m(X+Y)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}m(X+y_n)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}m(X)=+\infty$$

The second equality because the Lebesgue measure is invariant under translations and the second because $m(X)=d>0$.